# How do I perform an instant-kill mêlée attack?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In Tomb Raider multiplayer, there's this one player who is able to kill me with a semi-cinematic mêlée animation that isn't a stealth kill. Whenever I perform a mêlée attack, I just deal damage but not an animation like theirs. How do they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either (1) perform a mêlée attack at someone's back, while the skull prompt appears over the target's head (A.K.A. stealth kill), (2) perform a charge attack, or (3) perform a ledge kill.

(2) The charge attack is performed by holding your mêlée key and moving, reaching a target while the screen is darkened. (3) A ledge kill is performed by hanging from a ledge and performing a mêlée attack against a target who is within reach.